# How to get clock ticks per second using java?

Tags: java, c++

I need to get clock ticks per second using Java; I have searched so many web sites but I couldn't get the answer.

In C++ they are using following method to get clock ticks per second:

```
sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
```

But, I want to know how to get this in Java. Please share your ideas if it is possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Not claiming it is not possible, but it violates a java's principle of indepndency of the running environment

Comment: Smells like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain *why* you want this data?

Comment: Might System.nanoTime() be what you are looking for?

Comment: If this question is about the precision of System.nanoTime(), then a statistical analysis on the output of System.nanoTime() could reveal its precision. On recent Linux systems, at least gettimeofday() has a precision of a microsecond so I assume System.nanoTime() also has a very good precision. Anyway, assuming that sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) would be the same as the precision of System.nanoTime() would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't find a Java library to do this is because you would either need to implement it with a JNA / JNI call (i.e. a native library, not Java) or by calling some external application (i.e. not Java).

FWIW - I haven't managed to identify a Linux commands that gives this info, though it would be simple to write a little application in C / C++ to call `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` and output the result!